# Google Drive SDK feature request for > and < operators on title field

Tags: android, google-drive-api

The documentation at https://developers.google.com/drive/search-parameters indicates that the less than and the greater than operators do not apply to the file title field, which seems to prevent searching according to an alphabetical range. Below is my particular use case for alphabetical search.

I'm writing an Android application called [ftNote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.eduneer.ftnote) that provides gait analysis for runners wearing the application strapped to their calf as they run. The application provides some real-time feedback to the runner (e.g., high impact alarm and stride rate announcements) and also provides the option to log the sensor data that then gets uploaded to Google Drive for further analysis. The sensor data log files are saved in a queue of user specified length N (e.g., 5) of most recent logs and are named with a non-standard timestamp (e.g., 2013_04_25T13_25_40.bmp) to avoid the '-' and ':' characters that would possibly cause problems in Windows filenames. Although the accelerometer, magnetometer, and gyroscope sensors are sampled at 50 Hz, the resulting data is stored in less than 5 Mbytes per hour. Therefore it is conceivable that avid runners could save thousands of sensor data logs in their Google Drive account.

When uploading a local set of data sensor logs, ftNote first checks to see if the files already exist on Google Drive. It would be convenient if Google Drive could be queried for just the files with titles in the alphabetical range between the names of the first logged file and the last logged file in the queue of N files.

That's my particular use case at the moment, but it seems there are many others (e.g., an alphabetically indexed ListView). I hope my feature request makes sense. If not, please let me know what needs clarification.

Comment: are you saying you want to convert the title into a date and search by date created?

Comment: Directly searching through an alphabetical range of titles is the feature I'd like. But you are right that in my particular case I currently take the intermediate step of converting the title to a time stamp and search with that. Of course that approach wouldn't work for general titles.

Comment: You're right that we don't support range queries on the title field and it looks like there is no great workaround I can suggest. We're going to consider your feature request for the future releases. Btw, our community would be a better place for your feature requests: https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037 All development related questions are welcomed on Stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To recap (and take this question out of the unanswered list), [Burcu Dogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/92606/burcu-dogan) says the feature request will be considered and the preferred site to make future feature requests concerning Google Drive SDK is https://plus.google.com/communities/107264319205603895037